# randomly animate individual letters

Tags: jquery, random, jquery-animate

I have a sentence of words that i'm using jquery lettering to separate into individual letters.

the markup after it's processed would look like this

```
<div id="tagline">
<p>
<span class="char1">w</span>
<span class="char2">e</span>
<span class="char3"> </span>
<span class="char4">c</span>
<span class="char5">o</span>
</p>
</div>
```

etc etc

So I'm wondering how do I go about having a random letter getting animated every set interval.

like after a second, maybe 'c' fades out and in, then 'w' does that etc etc

All help appreciated!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do something at a set interval, use, um, `setInterval` :)

To pick a random child, use `Math.random`:

```
var letters = tagline.children();

setInterval(function() {
     letters.eq(Math.random() * letters.length | 0).fadeOut(500).fadeIn(500); // Or something
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Ok i've added var tagline = $("#tagline p"); above it. it's still not working. am i missing out on something? sorry i'm not too great with code

Comment: @JesperOng: Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that shows the problem, please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your span el's are set to - opacity: 0;

```
$('#tagline span').each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(200*index).animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 250);
});
```